# Unexpected sizeof struct with mixed bitfields and enum decls under mingw's gcc-5.3

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I have encoutered strange problem with mingw gcc, where `sizeof(X)` returns 8 instead of 4 in following example:

```
struct X
{
      enum E {e1, e2, e3};
      uint32_t v:2;
      enum E2 {ee1, ee2, ee3};
      uint32_t vv:1;
};
```

If I change it to

```
struct X
{
      enum E {e1, e2, e3};
      enum E2 {ee1, ee2, ee3};
      uint32_t v:2;
      uint32_t vv:1;
};
```

result becomes a 4, as expected.
I know that bitfield's alignment, ordering and other stuff is implementation-defined, but the same gcc 5.3 under Linux gives 4 with both samples.
As my point of view enum declaration cannot enlarges struct's size and affects to bit fields packings. So what's wrong with the first declaration?
Here is compilation command line:

```
C:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Documents/build-tst-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MinGW_32bit-Release'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -std=c++1z -std=gnu++1z -O2 -std=gnu++1z -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I..\tst -I. -I..\tst\magic_get\include -Ic://boost_1_62_0 -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtNetwork -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtSql -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o release\main.o ..\tst\main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o release\tst.exe release/main.o release/mainwindow.o release/moc_mainwindow.o  -lmingw32 -LC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\lib C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\lib\libqtmain.a -lshell32 -LC:\utils\my_sql\my_sql\lib -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Widgets.a C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Gui.a C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Network.a C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Sql.a C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Core.a 
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Documents/build-tst-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MinGW_32bit-Release'
```

Full example that works as expected can be found at [http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62d3a09d10fcc648](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97cf689f780de80b)
I have not find online mingw unfortunately to show unexpected results.

Comment: How come 2x quint32 could be 4? 2x4=8...

Comment: And link does not point to vaild example :)

Comment: @Anty it is not full-sized ints, it's a bit fields, check the example down the question, please

Comment: @Anty :) yeah, fixed for now

Comment: Why do you expect size 8? Are you running this on some old 16 bit DOS computer?

Comment: @Lundin I am expected 4, but got 8 instead

Comment: You say "sizeof X returns 8 but expect 4" but on a Windows PC you should expect 12 and get 16. Something is wrong with your question and/or setup.

Comment: I suspect your question doesn't make sense because `enum E { ...`  is not even valid C code. What did you expect those enums to do?

Comment: On Windows i got 8, on Linux i got 4. Why should I expected 12 or 16? v and vv is bit fields, and should be packed to one uint32_t

Comment: @Lundin it's a C++ code, not C, and it is valid, I use enum's concrete values out of struct.

Comment: Can't reproduce on gcc.godbolt.com, it gives me 4 in both cases. What does your `g++ --version` look like?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i checked on godbolt too, but there is no mingw-gcc. Output is `g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0`

Comment: I expected gcc 5.3 to be the same as mingw-gcc 5.3, but I guess they're not.

Comment: GCC can pack bitfields into storage units that are partially occupied by non-bitfield members. In this case, the reason that the total size is 4 must be that the `enum`s are considered to be byte wide due to their small range.   This couldn't work with C enums, because C enums must be wide enough to hold any `int` value; they are not type safe, like in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks it is a "feature" of gcc to be MSVC compatible.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Variable-Attributes.html

Please try

1) add attribute

```
struct __attribute__((gcc_struct)) X
{
      enum E {e1, e2, e3};
      uint32_t v:2;
      enum E2 {ee1, ee2, ee3};
      uint32_t vv:1;
};
```

2) add compile option `-mno-ms-bitfields`

Comment: Great, thank you. It works with `__attribute__` and -mno-ms-bitfields separately, so I can use one or another on my own